# Mean along columns considering only positive elements

Tags: python, pandas

I want to get mean among n columns but it should consider only positive values.

for ex:

```
d = {'col1': [1, 2,-4,5], 'col2': [3, 4,5,6], 'col3': [4,5,-6,-8], 'col4': [1,2,3,4]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

df

In this case the new column should get average of 4 column in first row and avg of 'col2'&'col4' in fourth row.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please add minimal reproducible example, or at least an attempt. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can mask it as `NaN` by `where`, notice the `mean` default `skipna` as True , which will not consider the NaN value

```
df.where(df>0).mean(1)
Out[128]: 
0    2.25
1    3.25
2    4.00
3    5.00
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

You can filter out the negative values with `df = df[(df > 0)]` and then call `.mean()`